# Why is there no activity on GPU between successive thrust sort and reduce commands?

Tags: sorting, cuda, gpu, thrust, nvvp

Please refer to the two snapshots below showing a Nvidia Visual Profiler session of my CUDA code:

**Snapshot from nvprof session showing thrust::sort and thrust::reduce call execution timeline**
[image: Snapshot from nvprof session showing thrust::sort and thrust::reduce call execution timeline]

**Highlighted the sort and reduce calls to show the times taken and the gap in between their execution**
[image: Highlighted the sort and reduce calls to show the times taken and the gap in between their execution]

You can see a gap of approximately 70 us between the two `thrust::sort()` calls, then there is a big gap between the first `thrust::reduce()` and the second `thrust::sort()` calls. In all there is approximately 300 us of such gaps visible in the snapshot. I believe these are '**idle**' times, perhaps introduced by the thrust library. Anyway, I couldn't find any relevant discussion, or a documentation on this by Nvidia. Can someone please explain why do I have such apparent '**idle**' times? Combined, such times account for 40% of my application execution time, so it is a big concern for me!

Also, I have measured that the gaps between calls to successive cuda kernels I wrote is about just 3 us!

I have written a sample cuda code in order to post here:

```
void profileThrustSortAndReduce(const int ARR_SIZE) {
    // for thrust::reduce on first 10% of the sorted array
    const int ARR_SIZE_BY_10 = ARR_SIZE / 10;

    // generate host random arrays of float
    float* h_arr1;          cudaMallocHost((void **)&h_arr1, ARR_SIZE * sizeof(float));
    float* h_arr2;          cudaMallocHost((void **)&h_arr2, ARR_SIZE * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        h_arr1[i] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX)* 1000.0f;
        h_arr2[i] = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX)* 1000.0f;
    }

    // device arrays populated
    float* d_arr1;          cudaMalloc((void **)&d_arr1, ARR_SIZE * sizeof(float));
    float* d_arr2;          cudaMalloc((void **)&d_arr2, ARR_SIZE * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(d_arr1, h_arr1, ARR_SIZE * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_arr2, h_arr2, ARR_SIZE * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // start cuda profiler
    cudaProfilerStart();

    // sort the two device arrays
    thrust::sort(thrust::device, d_arr1, d_arr1 + ARR_SIZE);
    thrust::sort(thrust::device, d_arr2, d_arr2 + ARR_SIZE);

    // mean of 100 percentiles of device array
    float arr1_red_100pc_mean = thrust::reduce(thrust::device, d_arr1, d_arr1 + ARR_SIZE) / ARR_SIZE;
    // mean of smallest 10 percentiles of device array
    float arr1_red_10pc_mean = thrust::reduce(thrust::device, d_arr1, d_arr1 + ARR_SIZE_BY_10) / ARR_SIZE_BY_10;

    // mean of 100 percentiles of device array
    float arr2_red_100pc_mean = thrust::reduce(thrust::device, d_arr2, d_arr2 + ARR_SIZE) / ARR_SIZE;
    // mean of smallest 10 percentiles of device array
    float arr2_red_10pc_mean = thrust::reduce(thrust::device, d_arr2, d_arr2 + ARR_SIZE_BY_10) / ARR_SIZE_BY_10;

    // stop cuda profiler
    cudaProfilerStop();
}
```

**Snapshot of nvprof session of this sample function**
[image: Snapshot of nvprof session of this sample function]

Comment: please post a [mcve] which exhibits the profiling snapshots

Comment: I have made changes, please let me know if there is anything I can add/modify to make this question better understandable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The gaps are primarily caused by `cudaMalloc` operations.  `thrust::sort` and presumably `thrust::reduce` allocate (and free) temporary storage associated with their activity.

You've cut this portion of the timeline off from the first 2 pictures you have pasted into your question, but immediately above the portion of the timeline you have shown in your 3rd picture, you will find `cudaMalloc` operations in the "runtime API" profiler line.

These `cudaMalloc` (and `cudaFree`) operations are time-consuming and synchronizing.  To work around this, the typical advice is to use a [thrust custom allocator](https://parallel-computing.pro/index.php/9-cuda/34-thrust-cuda-tip-reuse-temporary-buffers-across-transforms) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076377/static-thrust-custom-allocator)).  In so doing, you can allocate once for the necessary sizes needed, at the beginning of your program, and not have to incur the allocation/free overhead each time you make a thrust call.

Alternatively, you could explore [cub](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/), which already has the allocation and processing steps separated for you.